# Broadcast pairing: broadcastURL not valid

Tags: ios, broadcasting, pairing, replaykit

I'm using Broadcast pairing with ReplayKit2. In BroadcastSetupViewController when i'm calling `self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(withBroadcast: broadcastURL, setupInfo: setupInfo),` i've got the following error:

*[default] [ERROR] Failed to determine whether URL / (n) is managed by
 a file provider*

. 
I have the same message whatever url i give to broadcastURL.
Do you have any idea ?
Best!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?